# How to refresh a widget based on another widget's on tap method

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, flutter-widget

In my Flutter UI, I want to refresh the item list whenever a user chooses a particular category. I also want to make the chosen category become the active category. Here's how my UI looks like:

[image]

Here's my code which displays the categories:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     var categoriesData =   Provider.of<Categories>(context);
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: categoriesData.items
          .map(
            (catData) => CategoryItemNew(
                  id:catData.id,
                  title:catData.title,
                  isActive:categoriesData.items.indexOf(catData)==0?true:false
                ),
          )
          .toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Here's the code for each category item:

```
class CategoryItemNew extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  final String id;
  bool isActive;
  final Function press;
  CategoryItemNew({
    @required this.id,
    @required this.title,
    this.isActive
  });

  @override
  _CategoryItemNewState createState() => _CategoryItemNewState();
}

class _CategoryItemNewState extends State<CategoryItemNew> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => selectCategory(context),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 15),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              widget.title,
              style: widget.isActive
                  ? TextStyle(
                      color: kTextColor,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    )
                  : TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
            ),
            if (widget.isActive)
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
                height: 3,
                width: 22,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: kPrimaryColor,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                ),
              ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void selectCategory(BuildContext ctx) {
   // What should I do here? 
  }
}
```

And Here's the code to display the products:

```
class ItemList extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/item-list';
  String title = ''; 
  ItemList(this.title);  

  @override
  _ItemListState createState() => _ItemListState();
}

class _ItemListState extends State<ItemList> {
  var _isInit = true;
  var _isLoading = false;
 

   void didChangeDependencies() {
    if (_isInit) {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = true;
      });
       Provider.of<Products>(context).fetchAndSetProducts(widget.title, true).then((_) {
        setState(() {
          _isLoading = false;
        });
      });
    }
    _isInit = false;
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     final productsData =   Provider.of<Products>(context); 
    return _isLoading? CircularProgressIndicator():SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      child: Row(
         children:productsData.items
          .map(
            (productData) => ItemCard(
                  svgSrc: "assets/icons/burger_beer.svg",
                  //id:catData.id,
                  title: productData.title
                  //title:productData.title,
                ),
          )
          .toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When the app starts, I am able to fetch the categories and am also able to show the items for the "BURGERS & WRAPS" category. However, I don't know how to refresh the item list when user chooses another category and also how to make that category be the active category.

**Updated CategoryItem class after Mickael's reponse**

```
 String previousId =''; 
// ignore: must_be_immutable
class CategoryItemNew extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  final String id;
  bool isActive;
  final Function press;
  CategoryItemNew({
    @required this.id,
    @required this.title,
    this.isActive,
  });
  @override
  _CategoryItemNewState createState() => _CategoryItemNewState();

}

class _CategoryItemNewState extends State<CategoryItemNew> {

  String id; 
  ValueNotifier valueNotifier;
   
  void initState() {
    id = widget.id;
   valueNotifier = ValueNotifier(previousId);
   print('ID in initstate is ' + id); 
    super.initState();
  }

  isIdUpdated(String id) {
     print('previous in updateid is ' + previousId);
    if(previousId != id)
    { 
      previousId = id; 
     valueNotifier.value = id;
     print('ID in updateid is ' + id); 
    }
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => selectCategory(context),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 15),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              widget.title,
              style: widget.isActive
                  ? TextStyle(
                      color: kTextColor,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    )
                  : TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
            ),
            if (widget.isActive)
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
                height: 3,
                width: 22,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: kPrimaryColor,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                ),
              ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  ValueListenableBuilder selectCategory(BuildContext ctx) {
     isIdUpdated(id); 
   return ValueListenableBuilder(
      valueListenable: valueNotifier,
      builder: (context, value, child) {
        print('inside listenabele builder'); 
        return ItemList(widget.title);
      },
    );
  }

   
}
```

Notice that I have a print statement inside the builder of ValueListenableBuilder. This print statement never gets executed. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a ValueListener that will listen to the value of the categories you want to show. When you click on a category, you have to add the new value to your ValueListener.

Once it's done, create a [ValueListenableBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ValueListenableBuilder-class.html) which will build every time its value change. In the builder, you can show the widget you want according to the value you're listening.

EDIT : Same things for the "active" category, you can use the same value.

Comment: Can you provide an example based on the code I shared?

Comment: I did it like this but it doesn't trigger the itemlist class. What am I doing wrong? 
  ValueListenableBuilder selectCategory(BuildContext ctx) {
  print('Inside value listenable'); 
   ValueNotifier valueNotifier = ValueNotifier(widget.id);
   return ValueListenableBuilder(
      valueListenable: valueNotifier,
      builder: (context, value, child) {
        return ItemList(widget.title);
      },
    );
  }
}

Comment: valueNotifier = ValueNotifier(widget.id); is for initialization only. When you click on a category update your value like this : valueNotifier.add(clickValue); . After that, inside the builder of your ValueListenableBuilder you can return what you want in order to your ValueNotifier value like this : builder:(context,value,child) { if(value == 1) {return BugerList()} else if { return TacosList()} else ...

Comment: What would be the click value in my code ? I am assuming the category id?

Comment: It can be whatever you want. But in your case, yes the category id seems to be a good idea. To update your ValueNotifier, just try to add a GestureDetector that will catch the value of your category onClick. Something like : GestureDetector(onTap: (){ valueNotifier.add(category.id) }

Comment: how will the add method look like and where do I create it? Do I need a separate class for called ValueNotifier with an add method defined?

Comment: You're my heros! The [ValueListenableBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ValueListenableBuilder-class.html) is the secret sauce here! Updating values in different Widgets, thank you so much!